# Can I avoid brackets on Seq.iter?

Tags: f#, pipe

Or really can I avoid brackets with operations like this :

```
X |> Seq.iter(fun x -> () )
```

So I want to know if that is possible to make some trick with pipes alike or not. I already tried it with different ways but know I want to back on it and ask maybe I can do it using something like `| |`

```
X |> Seq.iter <| fun x ->
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `<|` is the same number of characters as `()`?

Comment: I guess -> operator's precedence is a little bit too low...

Comment: I would just use a named function. `X |> Seq.iter f`

Comment: The only occasion where I've found it useful to use `|>` and `<|` in the same expression is when calling `defaultArg`.

Comment: I want it because I dislike brackets )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can write:

```
for x in X do ()
```

Okay, that's not what you're asking for, but sequence expressions and `for` are often a syntactically simpler way for expressing pipelines.

Back to your question - the reason why `<|` doesn't work (for a longer pipeline) is that it has too low priority (because it has a different purpose in the first place). You'd need some operator that has higher priority than `|>` so that the code is parsed correctly. You can write for example:

```
let (+<) f a = f a

[1..10] |> Seq.map +< fun x -> x * x
        |> Seq.iter +< fun x -> printfn "%A" x
```

But really, it is not a good idea to use this in practice, because it doesn't save you any typing and it will confuse other F# programmers who will read your code (unlike in Haskell when using `$`).

Comment: Tomas, you just gave me the idea to use the `^` to make a right-associative backward pipe, `let inline (^<|) f a = f a`. Created my first snippit for it too: http://fssnip.net/4o

Comment: @Stephen: Just noticed the snippet via twitter :-). Nice & useful sample! Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of type inference, what you have is most likely the best way to do it. It allows the function `'a -> unit` to know the type of `'a` because `seq<'a>` is given first (and type inference works top-to-bottom / left-to-right). You can rearrange the expression a few different ways, but none will save keystrokes, and may prove more awkward.